# Check if application is running from a background task

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm creating an UWP application with a background task. I don't want to run the background when the real application is running or suspended. Is there some way to achieve that? I’ve looked on [SystemConditionType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br224835(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.applicationmodel.background.systemconditiontype)%3Bk(solutionitemsproject)%3Bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3Dv5.0)%3Bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true) but nothing fits what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since background tasks (except special ones) run in a separate process, there is not an elegant way to check if app is running or not since memory is not shared between the app and the background task. There are two ways that I implemented successfully:

**App Service**

[Create an app service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) in the app, in the background task, try to connect to the service. If service is available, it means that the app is running. This is the favorite one when you need communication between the task and the app.

**File Lock**

This is the favorite one in simple scenarios that you just need to know if the app is running or not.

1. Every time the app starts, create/open a file in local app folder, open it for write and keep it open as long as the app is running. Close it on Suspending event and re-open it on Resuming event.
2. In the background task, attempt to open the file for writing, if attempt was successful, it means that app is not running.
3. Close the file immediately in the background task.

**Note:**
In the new API that is available in anniversary update, background tasks may be executed in the [same process as the app](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/07/background-activity-with-the-single-process-model/). Using the new model, you won't have this problem anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’m looking forward run background threads in the same process as the app, it will certainly simplify things like this.

Comment: Trying to accomplish the 1st approach, however when trying to connect to the UI projects app service with the background tasks AppServiceConnection.OpenAsync() method noting happens Debug does not contunue nothing returns for the result. Any idea? (all insertions are OK in UI projects aminfest..) all settings OK. (build target in both : Anniversary, minimal: Anniversary)

Comment: @gericooper Do you get the task Deferral using the  taskInstance.GetDeferral() method before attempting to connect to the service? Otherwise, the task finishes because it does not wait for the async method (OpenAsync) to return.

Comment: no I don't. In fact it does not do anything. What is done so far:
- In the UI project I made a new class serves as the app service, implements IBackgroundTask
- In the already existed background task I'm trying to connect to this. However nothing happens after it reaches OpeanAsync()

Comment: App service declaration in the UI app package manifest's file are filled (Name and entry point) so cannot figure out what's wrong

Comment: @gericooper You need to call [taskInstance.GetDeferral()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.ibackgroundtaskinstance.getdeferral) before calling OpenAsync in the existed background task or it will terminate before OpenAsync returns. when you done the job in the background task, call deferral.Complete();